# Taxonomy doesn't follow slug permalink structure

Tags: custom-post-types, php, taxonomy

I started with a fresh template and added a `Post Type` according to specification at [GenerateWP](https://generatewp.com/post-type/).

I then added a taxonomy to the custom post type, also according to the above-referenced website:

```
// Register Custom Taxonomy
function addIssuesTaxonomy() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                       => _x( 'Issues', 'Taxonomy General Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'singular_name'              => _x( 'Issue', 'Taxonomy Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'menu_name'                  => __( 'Issues', 'text_domain' ),
        'all_items'                  => __( 'All Issues', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item'                => __( 'Parent Issue', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'          => __( 'Parent Issue:', 'text_domain' ),
        'new_item_name'              => __( 'New Issue Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new_item'               => __( 'Add New Issue', 'text_domain' ),
        'edit_item'                  => __( 'Edit Issue', 'text_domain' ),
        'update_item'                => __( 'Update Issue', 'text_domain' ),
        'view_item'                  => __( 'View Issue', 'text_domain' ),
        'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate issues with commas', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Add or remove issues', 'text_domain' ),
        'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Choose from the most used', 'text_domain' ),
        'popular_items'              => __( 'Popular Issues', 'text_domain' ),
        'search_items'               => __( 'Search Issues', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found'                  => __( 'Not Found', 'text_domain' ),
        'no_terms'                   => __( 'No items', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list'                 => __( 'Issues list', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list_navigation'      => __( 'Issues list navigation', 'text_domain' ),
    );
    $rewrite = array(
        'slug'                       => 'issues',
        'with_front'                 => true,
        'hierarchical'               => false,
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels'                     => $labels,
        'hierarchical'               => true,
        'public'                     => true,
        'show_ui'                    => true,
        'show_admin_column'          => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
        'show_tagcloud'              => true,
        'rewrite'                    => $rewrite,
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'issues', array( 'articles' ), $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'addIssuesTaxonomy', 0 );
```

I then saved the permalinks in this structure `http://xxx/sample-post/`, but no matter what, the newly added taxonomy does not show up at `http://xxx/issues`. Instead I get a 404. Navigating to `/articles/issues/` also results in 404.

What am I missing in order to display all `issues` found in the newly created taxonomy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no such page in WordPress. `/issues/` doesn't exist. All WordPress URLs display either a single post/page, or a list of posts/pages (search, date archives, category archives etc.). So there's no way WordPress will list *terms*. If you create a new issue, then that will be accessible at `/issues/issue-name/`, but nothing will exist on `/issues/` by itself.

If you want to list all issues, then the simplest method would be to create a *page* called Issues, then create a custom page template that lists all terms in the Issues taxonomy. You can do this with `get_terms()`:

```
$issues = get_terms( [ 'taxonomy' => 'issues' ] );

if ( ! is_wp_error( $issues ) && $issues ) {
    foreach( $issues as $issue ) {
        echo $issue->name; // Name of issue.
        echo get_term_link( $issue ); // URL to articles in that issue.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the pointer. I implemented your suggests, but unfortunately I get back an empty array although I created two `issues`

Comment: Check [the documentation for `get_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) default arguments. You might need to change some. For example, by default terms without posts are excluded.

Comment: Right on the money, thank you kindly:     $issues = get_terms( 
        array(
        'taxonomy' => 'issues',
        'hide_empty' => false
        )
    )